# How to add remote servers to my network?

Tags: networking, ip, virtual

I have several virtual machines running on a server in network **A**. However, I need them to act as if they are part of network **B** (IP-s, hostnames, etc.). What is the best approach to this?

EDIT: QEMU + KVM for virtualization.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to take a look at a [VPN network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) then. Then you can contact your servers as if they are in the same network.